# Redis MQ queue depth monitoring

Tags: c#, asp.net, redis, servicestack

In a project I am currently engaged in we are using a [Redis / ServiceStack Message Queue](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Messaging-and-Redis) combination. Sometimes these queues gets "congested" because some of the messages takes quite some time to process by the backend.

I would therefore like to create an "overview"/"monitoring" panel in the administration system - which is coded in ASP.net WebForms, in order to avoid people contacting me to tell them whether the queue is congested.

How would I go about diving into the queues and retrieving the amount of pending/dead messages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [MqStats](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.UseCases/blob/master/Reusability/MqStats.cs) service in the [Reusability](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.UseCases/tree/master/Reusability) example project that shows how to introspect and provide an overview of all Redis MQ's, whilst the [MqDump](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.UseCases/blob/master/Reusability/MqStats.cs#L165) service shows how to introspect messages of a single DTO Type.

Redis MQ's are just Redis server-side lists that are unique to each Request DTO which take the format of `mq:{DtoName}:{MQType}`, e.g:

```
mq:RequestDto:inq
mq:RequestDto:priorityq
mq:RequestDto:outq
mq:RequestDto:dlq
```

You can simply use Redis List operations against the above lists to count the number of messages in each mq (aka list) and introspect each one by deserializing it into a `Message` which you can re-use the [CreateMessage](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.UseCases/blob/master/Reusability/MqStats.cs#L212) method to do.